# Analytics in the CVAT stop working after clearing cache

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, cvat

Cvat Analytics stop working

My server disk space was full so to delete the cache I used the following commands:

`docker exec -it cvat_server bash -c 'rm -r data/*/*/export_cache/'`

`docker exec -it cvat_server bash -c 'rm -r data/cache/'`

After this, I am unable to get any data in analytics, As shown in the screenshot

[Please find attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJGuY.png)`

Please help